# Relative integral closure

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

**Definition:** Let $R$ be an $A$-algebra, where $R$ and $A$ are both commutative rings with unit.  Let $S \subset R$ be the (multiplicatively closed) subset consisting of those nonzerodivisors $s \in R$ such that $R/sR$ is flat over $A$.  I will call $R$ *integrally closed over $A$* if it satisfies

1. $R$ is flat over $A$, and
2. $R$ is integrally closed in $S^{-1}R$.

> Is $A[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ necessarily integrally closed over $A$?

If it is helpful, you may assume $A$ is noetherian, or even of finite type over a field.  But do not assume it is integral or reduced or anything like that.  (In the case I care about, $A$ is likely to be an open affine on a Hilbert or Quot scheme.)

Some thoughts: assuming things are noetherian, and I have not made an error, the condition for $s \in S$ is equivalent to the condition that $s$ pulls back to a nonzerodivisor on every fiber of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ over $\operatorname{Spec} A$.  This, in turn, is equivalent to the condition that $V(s)$ contains no associated component of any fiber.

If this "relatively integrally closed" condition is preserved under pullbacks, then the question has a positive answer.  However, the only reason I might even imagine that this is true is my hope that the condition I have given is a reasonably "natural" condition for a morphism to have.  I can't think of a way to begin arguing for preservation under pullbacks, and I don't even find it all that plausible.

Another, more plausible (to me) statement that would imply a positive answer is if normal morphisms (in the sense of Grothendieck) are necessarily "relatively integrally closed."  A morphism is normal if it is flat and its (geometric) fibers are normal.  I have a flawed argument for this: let $\ell \in S^{-1}R$ be integral over $R$. Then over each (geometric) fiber, $\ell$ is still integral over $R$, so $R \to R[\ell]$ pulls back to an isomorphism over each (geometric) fiber, and consequently must have been an isomorphism to begin with.  The flaw (that I've found and cannot seem to repair) is that, at least in principle, $R[\ell] \to S^{-1}R$ need not pull back to an injection.

---

**Note:** Will Sawin's answer below was incredibly helpful to me.  Please upvote it.

Comment: Is the set $S$ really multiplicatively closed? For instance, by definition of multiplicatively closed, $S$ must include $1$. This means the zero module $R/1\cdot R$ must be flat over $A$. Is zero module considered to be flat? Also, is clear why $S$ is multiplicatively closed?

Comment: Assuming my equivalent version of $S$ actually works, then $S$ is the intersection of all the $R \smallsetminus \mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ ranges over the associated primes of all the fibers of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ over $\operatorname{Spec} A$.  Thus, it is not only multiplicatively closed, but also saturated.  (For the non-noetherian case, I think I also have another argument using exact sequences, but I like this argument better.)

Comment: As for the flatness of the zero module: If you tensor any exact sequence by zero, you get a sequence in which all objects are zero, which is in particular exact.

Comment: Charles: I'll be happy to hear your argument with exact sequences...

Comment: darij: Since an extension of flat modules is flat, it suffices to show that the sequence $0 \to R/sR \stackrel{t}{\to} R/stR \to R/tR \to 0$ is exact.  The only question here is whether $R/sR \stackrel{t}{\to} R/stR$ is injective. Suppose, for some $a \in R$, that $t(a) \in stR$. Then there exists $b \in R$ such that $ta = stb$. Since $t$ is a nonzerodivisor in $R$, $a = sb$, so $a \in sR$. Thus, $a = 0$ mod $sR$. Hence, $R/stR$ is flat over $A$, as desired. (It's standard and easy that the product of nonzerodivisors is a nonzerodivisor--since a composite of injective functions is injective.)

Comment: I don't know why, but this problem makes me think of Koszul resolutions. If I had the slightest idea how to use them...

Comment: Actually, the way I would like to use this result involves Koszul resolutions.

Comment: @Charles: Here is an observation: Suppose $R$ is local and Noetherian and we want to define $S$. If $R$ is *not* flat over $A$, and $s\in R$ is a nonzerodivisor but *not* a unit, then $R/sR$ cannot be flat over $A$ (see Matsumura, Theorem 22.2, p. 173). So in this case $S^{-1}R=R$.

On the other hand, suppose $R$ is as above, but we don't know whether $R$ is flat over $A$ or not. Then if there is a nonzerodivisor $s\in R$ that is not a unit and $R/sR$ is flat over $A$, then $R$ itself is flat over $A$. In that case condition (1) in your definition of integrally closed is superfluous.

Comment: Your condition is not preserved under pullbacks. If $A=k[t]$, and $R=k[x,y,t]/\langle xy-t\rangle$ then $R$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions, so it is also integrally closed in $S^{-1}R$. However, the fiber over $A/\langle t\rangle$ is $k[x,y]/\langle xy \rangle$, which is not normal. In particular, $A \rightarrow R$ is not a normal morphism in the sense of Grothendieck.

I'm not sure if this is useful to your application, but I know that seminormality is sometimes used in place of normality because of the limitation that it is not possible to normalize in families.

Comment: Dustin: Thanks for your comment. If you look at the bottom of Will Sawin's answer, he and I came to the conclusion that the statement fails if $A$ is not reduced, which offers a huge family of counterexamples to the claim that the condition is preserved under pullbacks.  However, your example (in which all schemes in question are reduced) is also a useful example. Perhaps you address a more interesting question. (Apparently, integral closure is rarely useful in a non-reduced setting anyway, since any nilpotent is automatically integral over everything.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S$ consists of polynomials whose coefficients are not in any ideal, that is, polynomials whose coefficients generate the unit ideal.

First assume $A$ is integral. Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$, then clearly $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is an integrally closed unique factorization domain. Given an element in this that is in $S^{-1}R$, we seek to prove it is in $R$. We're writing a polynomial over $K$ as a fraction $x/y$ of polynomials over $A$. To make it a polynomial, every prime in $y$ must be paired with a prime in $x$. Their ratio is an element of $K$, such that multiplied by every coefficient of the prime in $x$, that is, every generator of the unit ideal, gets an element in $A$. Therefore it must be an element of $A$. So you can cancel them and leave an element of $A$ in $X$. This allows you to cancel everything in $x$, including constant terms, which must be units. We are left with a polynomial in $R$.

Now suppose $A$ is not integral. We're going to attempt to do this analysis separately on every prime ideal. Let $T$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $S^{-1}R$. The prime ideals of $A$ extend to $T$. Let $t$ be an element of $T$, then $A/p$ is an integral domain and so $t$ is an element of $R$ plus something in $p$. Given another prime, $q$, we "glue together" these characterizations.  We have a residue in $R/p$ and a residue in $R/q$, which agree in $R/(p+q)\subset T/(p+q)$. This makes $t$ an element of $A$ mod any finite set of primes, by a stronger version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. This is enough for reduced Noetherian schemes - choose the generic points of the irreducible components of $\textrm{Spec} A$.

EDIT: As Charles pointed out, this fails for any non-reduced scheme. Adjoin two invariants $x,y$, let $\epsilon$ be nilpotent, then $\epsilon x/y$ is nilpotent and so integral, but $\epsilon x$ is not a multiple of $y$ in $R$.

Comment: I'm not understanding the sentence, "Their ratio is a rational number that multiplied with the unit ideal gives an ideal of $A$."

Comment: Sorry the original was so messed up. Better?

Comment: Better, but I'm still not seeing why (in the case $A$ is a domain) it should hold that $(\text{ratio of prime factors}) \times (\text{prime factor of }x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $A$.

Comment: This is what I came up with while trying to follow your argument for $A$ a domain: We have $x/y=f/a$, where $a \in A$. Tensor the exact sequence $0 \to R \stackrel{y}{\to} R \to R/yR \to 0$ by $A/aA$. This gives a short exact sequence since $R/yR$ is flat, which in particular shows that $y$ is a nonzerodivisor on $R/aR$. Since $yf=ax\in aR$, we know $f \in aR$. Hence, $x/y=f/a$ lies in $R[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. I assume this is on some level equivalent to your argument.

Comment: I'd guess it is, but I don't see it directly. Your argument seems to remove the necessity for (in generalizations) the map to be generically an UFD, just generically integrally closed.

Comment: Do you have a reference or argument for the fact that ($\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ primes, neither containing the other) if $a \in R/\mathfrak{p}$ and $b \in R/\mathfrak{q}$ have the same residue mod $\mathfrak{p}+\mathfrak{q}$, then there is an element of $R/(\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathfrak{q})$ that maps to each of them? I'm sure this is true by the "glueing" idea you mention, but I can't think of a rigorous proof.

Comment: It's a version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. You can take $a$ and $b$ to be $0$ mod $p+q$, by just choosing an element of $R/(p\cap q)$ that has the correct residue. Therefore $a$ is in $q/p$ and $b$ is in $p/q$. Then you just take a representative for each and add them together. Something in $q/p$ is zero mod $q$, and vice versa.

You can probably say this by showing that $R/(p\cap q) \to R/p \times R/q \to R/(p+q)$ is exact.

Comment: Thanks. (I do think this is stronger than the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which can be proved using "functions" that are one on one component and zero on all the others.) Right now I'm trying to figure out what you mean by "ignoring" things in the discussion of nilpotents. I'm also a bit bothered by the fact that every nilpotent is automatically integral over anything since it satisfies the monic polynomial $x^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Formally, ignoring an ideal means that we can do the calculation over $A/I$ and get a final representation in $R/I$ and add anything in $I$ and get the right answer. This comes about for two reasons. First, once we get the final representation in $R$ we are multiplying by an element $f\in A$ which satisfies $fI=0$. Second, the elements of $I$ are nilpotent which means that adding or subtracting them does not change whether something is in $S$, since $S$ cares only about what happens at prime ideals.

Comment: Therefore an expression of the form $fx/y$ will not change, either in value, or in being a member of $S^{-1}R$, if we add elements of $I$ to $x$ and to $y$. So we can translate the problem of showing $fx/y$ is in $R$ to showing $x/y$ is in $R/I$, which turns out to be another version of the same problem, just with slightly fewer nilpotents.

Comment: So, suppose $A=\Bbbk[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$, and $R=A[x,y]$. How would you show that $x\epsilon/y \in A[x,y]$?  (It's integral since it squares to zero.) Based on this example, I'm actually inclined to doubt that the statement holds if $A$ is not reduced.

Comment: In your notation: just because $fx/y$ is integral over $R$, does not seem to imply that $x/y$ is integral over $R$; so I don't see how your "translation" could work.

Comment: That is a very good point. In fact, I think it is actually not the case that $x\epsilon/y$ is in $A[x,y]$, so the statement should tend to fail when $A$ is not reduced.

Comment: This answer, in spite of its shortcomings, turned out to be incredibly helpful for me. Please upvote it.

Comment: Will, please upvote the comment above so that people can see it.

Comment: For algebraic non-geometers, can you edit the original post to include a summary of what was proven here? I don't want to waste time searching for a counterexample to something that has been proved, or vice versa.

Comment: This now only contains statements I believe to be correct.